# Тире или двоеточие необходимо в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

**По двое, по трое, поодиночке: плавали они у кромки не растаявшего льда.**
Сомневаюсь в двоеточии. Следует ли его заменить на тире?

Comment: Мы не выполняем д/з, но можем помочь и поправить, если вы дополните вопрос своими рассуждениями.

Comment: Это не д/з, я не уверена в правильности своего ответа, поэтому решила проверить.
Моя версия выглядит примерно так: По двое, по трое, поодиночке: плавали они у кромки не растаявшего льда. Сомневаюсь в двоеточии. Следует ли его заменить на тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По двое, по трое, поодиночке // плавали они у кромки **нерастаявшего** льда.

Знаки препинания не нужны, здесь нет обособления, но есть инверсия (перестановка) обстоятельственного ряда. Поэтому кажется, что его нужно как-то обособить. На самом деле ряд уже выделен грамматически (с помощью инверсии), и другого выделения не требуется. Даже авторское тире здесь вряд ли можно поставить.

(Сочетание без перестановки: плавали по двое, по трое, поодиночке).

По поводу произношения. Пауза там действительно присутствует, но это обычная пауза (остановка голоса), которая  делит любое простое предложение на две части. Получается, что весь обстоятельственный ряд относится к первой части предложения.

Примечание: одиночное причастие пишется слитно с"не": нерастаявший. Сравнить: еще не растаявший, раздельное написание при наличии зависимого слова.

Comment: Особое спасибо, что заметили *нерастаявший*. После этого я исправил эту ошибку в своем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, корректно будет так:

**По двое, по трое, поодиночке плавали они у кромки нерастаявшего льда.**

Плавали как? По двое, по трое, поодиночке. Нет причин ставить двоеточие. Тире возможно, но как авторское.

Примечание: *нерастаявшего* пишут слитно (см. ответ Ксении).